# jQuery detect if textarea is empty

Tags: jquery

I am trying to determine if a textarea is empty if a user deletes what is already pre-populated in the textarea using jQuery.

Anyway to do this?

This is what I have and its not working

```
$(textarea).live('change', function(){
            if($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(submitButtonClass).addClass('disabled_button');
                $(submitButtonClass).removeClass('transSubmit');
            } else {
                $('.disabled_button').addClass('transSubmit').css({
                    'cursor':'pointer'
                }).removeClass('disabled_button');
            }
        });
```

Comment: is `textarea` an actual variable name in your code or did you forget to wrap it in string delimiters? e.g. `$("textarea").live(...)`.  What you have should work, otherwise.  Do you get any errors?

Comment: `textarea` is a variable name. And I am not getting any errors... I almost need to bind the keydown event to the textarea

Comment: if `textarea` isn't a selector, you should be using `bind` rather than `live`.  See http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats

Comment: @Andy: I placed my working code below

Answer (score 114):

```
if (!$("#myTextArea").val()) {
    // textarea is empty
}
```

You can also use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to make sure the element doesn't contain only white-space:

```
if (!$.trim($("#myTextArea").val())) {
    // textarea is empty or contains only white-space
}
```

Comment: @jaminator: works fine for me, there's no incompatible code. If you've tried it and it doesn't work then it's likely the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: this works on Chrome: if (!($.trim($('#ticket-notes-tickets').val())==="")) { ...}

Comment: i used: !$.trim($('.textAreaTD').text())

Answer (score 10):

```
if (!$.trim($("element").val())) {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know you are long past getting a solution. So, this is for others that come along to see how other people are solving the same common problem-- like me.

The examples in the question and answers indicates the use of jQuery and I am using the .change listener/handler/whatever to see if my textarea changes. This should take care of manual text changes, automated text changes, etc. to trigger the

```
//pseudocode
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#textarea').change(function () {
        if ($.trim($('#textarea').val()).length < 1) {

            $('#output').html('Someway your box is being reported as empty... sadness.');

        } else {

            $('#output').html('Your users managed to put something in the box!');
            //No guarantee it isn't mindless gibberish, sorry.

        }
    });
});
```

Seems to work on all the browsers I use. http://jsfiddle.net/Q3LW6/. Message shows when textarea loses focus.

**Newer, more thorough example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BradChesney79/tjj6338a/

Uses and reports .change(), .blur(), .keydown(), .keyup(), .mousedown(), .mouseup(), .click(), mouseleave(), and .setInterval().

Answer (score 4):

To find out if the textarea is empty we have a look at the textarea text content and if there is one sinlge character to be found it is not empty.

Try:

```
if ($(#textareaid).get(0).textContent.length == 0){
  // action
}
//or
if (document.getElmentById(textareaid).textContent.length == 0){
  // action
}
```

`$(#textareaid)` gets us the textarea jQuery object.
`$(#textareaid).get(0)` gets us the dom node.
We could also use `document.getElmentById(textareaid)` without the use of jQuery.
`.textContent` gets us the textContent of that dom element.
With `.length` we can see if there are any characters present.
So the textarea is empty in case that there are no characters inside.

Comment: .text() is not a function

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to get the value of the texbox and see if it has anything in it:

```
if (!$(`#textareaid`).val().length)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: `.length` is a number, not a function.

Comment: Does val() trim? If not, I would trim the trailing white-space just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code

```
function emptyTextAreaCheck(textarea, submitButtonClass) {
        if(!submitButtonClass)
            submitButtonClass = ".transSubmit";

            if($(textarea).val() == '') {
                $(submitButtonClass).addClass('disabled_button');
                $(submitButtonClass).removeClass('transSubmit');
            }

        $(textarea).live('focus keydown keyup', function(){
            if($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(submitButtonClass).addClass('disabled_button');
                $(submitButtonClass).removeClass('transSubmit');
            } else {
                $('.disabled_button').addClass('transSubmit').css({
                    'cursor':'pointer'
                }).removeClass('disabled_button');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Won't catch paste, cut, drop, etc.  Try [my plugin](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event) for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help suggestion man! I am going to look into this plugin... looks like a much better solution than what I am doing

Comment: The link @AndyE provided is dead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$('element').val()) {
   // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check for empty textarea as well as will not allow only Spaces in textarea coz that looks empty too.

```
 var txt_msg = $("textarea").val();

 if (txt_msg.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length == 0 || txt_msg=="") {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Andy E's answer helped me get the correct way to working for me:

```
$.each(["input[type=text][value=]", "textarea"], function (index, element) {
if (!$(element).val() || !$(element).text()) {
 $(element).css("background-color", "rgba(255,227,3, 0.2)");
}
});
```

This `!$(element).val()` did not catch an empty textarea for me.  but that whole bang (!) thing did work when combined with text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(["input[type=text][value=]", "textarea[value=]"], function (index, element) {
              //only empty input and textarea will come here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this and it should work in most cases, feel free to correct me if I am wrong :

```
function hereLies(obj) { 
  if(obj.val() != "") { 
    //Do this here 
  }
}
```

Where `obj` is the object of your `textarea`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<textarea placeholder="Insert text here..." rows="5" cols="12"></textarea>
<button id="checkerx">Check</button>
<p>Value is not null!</p>

<script>
  $("p").hide();
  $("#checkerx").click(function(){
      if($("textarea").val() != ""){
        $("p").show();
      }
      else{
       $("p").replaceWith("<p>Value is null!</p>");
      }
  });

</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `$("#element).val() === false` or `!$("#element).val()` did not work for me.

Instead, this worked:

```
// Check if element is empty
if ($("#element").val() === "") {
    // Element is empty! Do stuff here
}
```